# Retrieving summary total from another sheet based on current date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a Macro in Excel 2010 that can pull data from sheet 2 based on the date that the macro is run, and provide a total of the different drawing statuses in sheet 1 based on the drawing statuses given in sheet 2.  For example, if I run the macro on 3/18/2011, the sheet 1 (3/18/2011) Row should have the totals of ColB = 4, ColC = 0, ColD = 2, ColE = 1, ColF = 3.  So each day I run the macro, sheet 1 will get updated based on the current date and updated data from sheet 2 on the same file.  Can anyone give me a hint on how to start this code?

Sheet 1 data is as follows:

```
  A         B         C       D          E          F    
 Date  Preliminary  Review  Design  Construction  Final
```

The Date column has the following rows:

3/18/2011
3/20/2011
3/21/2011
3/22/2011

and so one till end of the month

Sheet 2 data is as follows:

Col L has the drawing numbers while Col M has the drawing status.  Below is the drawing number with status on sheet 2

```
    L             M

**Drawing       Status**

DWGT2010001     Design

DWGT2010002     Preliminary

DWGT2010003     Final

DWGT2010004     Preliminary

DWGT2010005     Design

DWGT2010006     Construction

DWGT2010007     Final

DWGT2010008     Preliminary

DWGT2010009     Preliminary

DWGT2010010     Final
```

Comment: Your columns D and F have the same name, and the string 'Final' on sheet two doesn't match any column.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully correctly.  Now what I need to know is if Sheet2 changes every day and is date specific, or is there some other mechanism so that you know which fields on Sheet 2 apply for any given date?

Comment: Lance, Sheet2 is updated and pulled from another database on a daily basis. For example, on 3/18/11, DWGT2010001 is listed as Design on sheet2 but it might be listed as Construction stage three days later and therefore the count is updated on a daily basis.  I just pulled the sample data for 10 rows only, but the actually data will be more than 10K rows.

Comment: So if I run the macro today, the row with date 3/18/11 in sheet1 will get updated with the count summary from sheet2.  I hope that made sense. I was thinking of doing some sort of DO WHILE with IF and Then commmands for the macro. Thanks for updating the table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, though you could modify it more based on your specific layout.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WorkingRow As Range
Dim StatusColumn As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ColumnNames(1 To 5) As String

Set WorkingRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Find(Date, LookIn:=xlValues, _  
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Rows(1)
StatusColumn = 13 ' Column M on Sheet 2
ColumnNames(1) = "Preliminary"
ColumnNames(2) = "Review"
ColumnNames(3) = "Design"
ColumnNames(4) = "Construction"
ColumnNames(5) = "Final"

For i = 1 To 5
  WorkingRow.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = _  
    Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(StatusColumn), ColumnNames(i))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Lance.  That code worked perfectly for my sample file.  I took out the "_" at the end of line 6 and it worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Actually the "_" is needed, so it works now with using the original code.  Thanks Lance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood well what you wanted to do...

As a start, you can try to record a macro doing what you want and adapt the code :
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-macro-HP005204711.aspx

Comment: JMax, basically sheet 1 has the summary of the drawing status by date and that info comes from sheet 2 data table and this is updated by the date you run macro.  The example i listed shows what the result is based on today's date (3/18/2011).  Record macro does not do today's date since this is going to be automated and anyone who pulls this worksheet should be able to see the current days cumulative totals.

Comment: Lance, you are right.  Col F on sheet 1 should be Final instead of Design